# Parsing JSON array from Tuple

Tags: c, arrays, json, tuples, pebble-watch

So I'm trying to follow the Pebble SDK over [here](http://developer.getpebble.com/sdkref/group___dictionary.html) alongside the [httpebble](https://github.com/Katharine/httpebble-watch) library.

Assume `DictionaryIterator* received` contains the following JSON payload:

```
{"0":["Oz Lotto","Powerball","TattsLotto","Super 66","Monday & Wednesday Lotto","The Pools"],"1":["17, 26, 38, 7, 36, 45, 9 (44) (41)","15, 37, 32, 6, 24, 10 (11)","37, 12, 15, 16, 42, 45 (6) (9)","1, 8, 5, 8, 8, 5","16, 40, 44, 8, 24, 15 (39) (3)","5, 17, 20, 22, 27, 31 (16)"]}
```

***main.c***:

I want to be able to extract the data to later store them into a list in my Pebble app. I'm having a bit of trouble grasping how a `Tuple` works though.

This is what I have so far, except I'm afraid I'm not sure how to actually extract values out of `lotto_names` and `lotto_numbers`.

```
void http_success(int32_t request_id, int http_status, DictionaryIterator* received, void* context) {
    if (request_id != HTTP_COOKIE) {
        return;
    }

    Tuple *lotto_names = dict_find(received, 0);
    Tuple *lotto_numbers = dict_find(received, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const char* lotto_name = lotto_names[i]; // ?
    }
}
```

I've also asked the question over at the [Pebble SDK forum](http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/7164/parsing-json-array-for-an-app#latest). However noone has responded to my post. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Taking a look at that SDK, it doesn't look like a straight-forward JSON tool.  It looks like the dictionary needs numeric keys to represent the data.  Are the "0" and "1" converted into the dictionary keys, and the values stored as strings in the dictionary?  Perhaps a JSON library would be good to use.

Comment: @ash: Great question, I'm using a library called [httpebble](https://github.com/Katharine/httpebble-watch), which I believe does that.

Comment: I don't see it in the API for the dictionary, but I could be missing it.  Here's a great site for JSON references: http://json.org/.  Here's one that I believe I've used from there: https://github.com/json-c/json-c/wiki.  Note that some libs I've tried to use in the past didn't correctly handle quoting.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the key "0" is associated to an array which is a form of nesting. As explained in [httpebble documentation](https://github.com/Katharine/httpebble-watch), there cannot be any nesting in the dictionary you return to `httpebble.

> The key/value pairs attached to the request are sent as a flat JSON dictionary. There cannot be any nesting.

You need to rework your JSON data to send keys associated directly with values.